# Load .obj filest in Threejs using parse

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to load .obj file in three.js scene given the content of the file not the file. What I mean is that OBJLoader gives me a function load which requires url. Is there a way to parse the content of the file and dont use url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup!

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var object = loader.parse( text );
```